# connect to mac from visual studio not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Visual studio 2019 on my Windows pc. I'm developing iOS mobile application using Xamarin in visual studio.In order to build my iOS app, I need to connect with mac machine. In order to achieve connection, when I click on "Pair to Mac" button (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin-> iOS Settings)
[image]

Ideally upon clicking the "Pair to Mac" button, I should see the dialog to connect with mac machine as shown in image below.

[image]

But in my case, I'm not getting any dialog upon clicking "Pair to Mac" button. I understand this could be setup related issue and hence I tried repair and even clean reinstall of my Visual studio 2019 instance. On my other machine, I'm able to see connection dialog upon pressing the "Pair to mac" button but just one of my machine has this issue.

I'm clueless what is wrong with my this particular machine. Any help on what I'm missing or what should I check?

Thanks for help,

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so just a guess: Did you possibly tick the "Don't show this again" box at the bottom left? On the working machine does that dialog do anything or is it just informational?

Comment: 2nd dialog should appear on the windows machine only and it is wizard which will help to connect with mac. 

Whatever is required from Mac side to connect, I have already done but problem is I'm not seeing 2nd dialog on windows to proceed with connection.

Comment: How about click the `Pair to Mac` icon in tool bar or choose form tools->ios-> `Pair to Mac`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually it turned out that my local copy of project had some issue and because of that I was not able to see "Connection wizard dialog" upon clicking "Pair to Mac". I took copy of my project from source control and then I was able to see the dialog upon clicking the "Pair to Mac" button. I could not figure out the exact cause though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to go to Options/Xamarin/Apple Account to click the button pair to mac and the dialog came up and worked there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to mobile development, but I found the only reliable solution to being unable to pair my windows development machine with my mac mini was to restart my router and purge all network connections from both my windows machine and mac. If restarting your router doesn't work the first time, just keep doing it a few times and eventually it should allow your machine to pair to mac. I also found this isn't exclusively a visual studio issue. Even remotely connecting from another program like FileZilla or SSH via command line yields the same results.

Ensure you follow the instructions on this page first:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-8.0

I have yet to understand what the mac is doing that periodically prevents remote connections. There are no other issues with other devices on the same network.

Edit: Another solution that works for me is to make your phone a WiFi hotspot, connect all your devices to it and try again.